# How to make RxJava interval to perform action instantly

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Hello I am making observable to ask my server about its online/offline status every 15 seconds:

```
public Observable<Response> repeatCheckServerStatus(int intervalSec, final String path) {
        return Observable.interval(intervalSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Response>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Response> call(Long aLong) {
                        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Response>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(Subscriber<? super Response> subscriber) {
                                try {
                                    Response response = client.newCall(new Request.Builder()
                                            .url(path + API_ACTION_CHECK_ONLINE_STATUS)
                                            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                                            .get()
                                            .build()).execute();

                                    subscriber.onNext(response);
                                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                                    if (!response.isSuccessful())
                                        subscriber.onError(new Exception());
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    subscriber.onError(e);
                                }
                            }
                        })
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
                    }
                });

    }
```

After I call this method, first execution of code will be after intervalSec time (15sec in my case). Looking at rxJava docummentation of interval method:

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html

This is how it should be.

Question: is there any way to execute code instantly and then repeat in intervals?

Comment: The accepted answer is great. One followup I would recommend would be to look at the observe scheduler itself if you really want it to be 'instant'. I created (closed source for now unfortunately, might try to upstream to RxAndroid) a Scheduler that wraps AndroidSchedulers.mainThread and executes tasks immediately (using a queue) if we are on the UI thread already (`Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()'). The `startWith`, which should be synchronous, should execute immediately instead of posting to the main thread for later, and fallback to RxAndroid if we are not on the main thread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`startWith`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html)

```
Observable.interval(15, SECONDS).startWith(1);
```

This will get the updates from the interval, but emit one item immediately after subscribing.

Answer (score 55):

You can execute it immediately also like this:

```
Observable.interval(0, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe();
```

Comment: This should really be the selected answer

Answer (score -2):

you can use `

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).startWith(0)
```

`
It is duplicate value "0"  in subscribe.